# Python zip(): Check which iterable got exhausted

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, generator

In Python 3, `zip(*iterables)` as of the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#zip)

> Returns an iterator of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables. The iterator stops when the shortest input iterable is exhausted.

As an example, I am running

```
for x in zip(a,b):
  f(x)
```

Is there a way to find out which of the iterables, `a` or `b`, led to the stopping of the zip iterator?

Assume that `len()` is not reliable and iterating over both `a` and `b` to check their lengths is not feasible.

Comment: What are you intending to do with the result? This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832). For example you might be better off using [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) instead of `zip`.

Comment: BTW, welcome to SO! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: @wjandrea Thanks! My intention is to make sure that the first of the two iterators is the one that gets exhausted, and to raise an exception otherwise. A potential workaround might be iterating only over `a` and obtaining `next(b)` within the loop, but I'm not sure if this is exactly the same in case `a` is shorter.

Answer (score 2):

I found the following solution which replaces `zip` with a `for` loop over only the first iterable and iterates over the second one inside the loop.

```
ib = iter(b)

for r in a:
    try:
        s = next(ib)
    except StopIteration:
        print('Only b exhausted.')
        break
    print((r,s))
else: 
    try:
        s = next(ib)
        print('Only a exhausted.')
    except StopIteration:
        print('a and b exhausted.')
```

Here `ib = iter(b)` makes sure that it also works if `b` is a sequence or generator object. `print((r,s))` would be replaced by `f(x)` from the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think Jan has the best answer. Basically, you want to handle the last iteration from zip separately.

```py
import itertools as it

a = (x for x in range(5))
b = (x for x in range(3))

iterables = ((it.chain(g,[f"generator {i} was exhausted"]) for i,g in enumerate([a,b])))

for i, j in zip(*iterables):
    print(i, j)

# 0 0
# 1 1
# 2 2
# 3 generator 1 was exhausted
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only two iterables, you can use the below code. `The exhausted[0]` will have your indicator for which iterator was exhausted. Value of None means both were exhausted.

However I must say that I do not agree with `len()` not being reliable. In fact, you should depend on the `len()` call to determine the answer. (unless you tell us the reason why you can not.)

```
def f(val):
    print(val)

def manual_iter(a,b, exhausted):
    iters = [iter(it) for it in [a,b]]
    iter_map = {}
    iter_map[iters[0]] = 'first'
    iter_map[iters[1]] = 'second'

    while 1:
        values = []
        for i, it in enumerate(iters):
            try:
                value = next(it)
            except StopIteration:
                if i == 0:
                    try:
                        next(iters[1])
                    except StopIteration:
                        return None
                exhausted.append(iter_map[it])
                return iter_map[it]
            values.append(value)
        yield tuple(values)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    exhausted = []
    a = [1,2,3]
    b = [10,20,30]
    for x in manual_iter(a,b, exhausted):
        f(x)
    print(exhausted)

    exhausted = []
    a = [1,2,3,4]
    b = [10,20,30]
    for x in manual_iter(a,b, exhausted):
        f(x)
    print(exhausted)

    exhausted = []
    a = [1,2,3]
    b = [10,20,30,40]
    for x in manual_iter(a,b, exhausted):
        f(x)
    print(exhausted)
```

Answer (score -3):

See below for by me written function `zzip()` which will do what you want to achieve. It uses the `zip_longest` method from the `itertools`  module and returns a tuple with what `zip` would return plus a list of indices which if not empty shows at which 0-based position(s) was/were the iterable/iterables) becoming exhausted before other ones:

```
def zzip(*args): 
    """ Returns a tuple with the result of zip(*args) as list and a list 
    with ZERO-based indices of iterables passed to zzip which got 
    exhausted before other ones. """
    from itertools import zip_longest
    nanNANaN = 'nanNANaN'
    Zipped  = list(zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=nanNANaN))
    ZippedT = list(zip(*Zipped))
    Indx_exhausted = []
    indx_nanNANaN  = None
    for i in range(len(args)):
        try: # gives ValueError if nanNANaN is not in the column
            indx_nanNANaN = ZippedT[i].index(nanNANaN)
            Indx_exhausted += [(indx_nanNANaN, i)]
        except ValueError:
            pass 
    if Indx_exhausted: # list not empty, iterables were not same length
        Indx_exhausted.sort()
        min_indx_nanNANaN = Indx_exhausted[0][0] 
        Indx_exhausted = [ 
            i for n, i in Indx_exhausted if n == min_indx_nanNANaN ]
        return (Zipped[:min_indx_nanNANaN], Indx_exhausted)
    else: 
        return (Zipped, Indx_exhausted)

assert zzip(iter([1,2,3]),[4,5],iter([6]))  ==([(1,4,6)],[2])
assert zzip(iter([1,2]),[3,4,5],iter([6,7]))==([(1,3,6),(2,4,7)],[0,2])
assert zzip([1,2],[3,4],[5,6])              ==([(1,3,5),(2,4,6)],[])
```

The code above runs without raising an assertion error on the used test cases.

Notice that the 'for loop' in the function loops over the items of the passed parameter list and not over the elements of the passed iterables.